# finding the angle of the headset in VR using three js

Tags: three.js, virtual-reality

I'm trying to figure out how to get the headset angle (camera angle) of the headset in VR using ThreeJS. I'm using an oculus quest 2

I've tried:

var cameraAngle=new THREE.Vector3();

camera.getWorldDirection(cameraAngle);

But I just get a result in cameraAngle of (0,0,1), I see lots of examples out there all very similar but none seem to work properly. It looks like something changed recently in the three js?

I was able to capture the headset (camera) position, but just can't seem to get the angle.

Can someone help out?